# Submit tasks that run in parallel over multiple CPUs

Tags: slurm

Running my code does not require much time. When I launch multiple runs on my laptop, I use joblib and it works nicely.  I now want to launch my runs on a Slurm-based cluster.  I can't understand what resources to ask such that: multiple runs are launched on 1 node over many CPUs in parallel. I have a loop to submit jobs, but I don't know how to specify `nodes`, `tasks`, `cpus_per_task`, and `array`.
My code is based on `submitit` and here is how it looks like

```py
import submitit
from main import run
seeds = range(0, 100)
datasets = ['x', 'y']

for seed in seeds:
    for data in datasets:
      executor = submitit.AutoExecutor(folder="./out")
      executor.update_parameters(
          timeout_min=10,
          nodes=1,
          cpus_per_task=2,
          mem_gb=1,
          slurm_array_parallelism=10,
      )
      job = executor.submit(run, seed, data)
      print(f"Submitted job: {job.job_id}")
```

I'd need help understanding how to set the parameters. Slurm doc is confusin and I can't find the doc for Submitit parameters.